# koa, sessions, redis: how to make it work?

Tags: session, redis, koa

I am trying to implement Firebase authentication with server-side sessions using koa, koa-session, koa-redis.

I just can't grasp it. When reading the koa-session readme, this is particularly cryptic to me ([link](https://github.com/koajs/session#external-session-stores)):

> You can store the session content in external stores (Redis, MongoDB or other DBs) by passing options.store with three methods (these need to be async functions):
>
> get(key, maxAge, { rolling }): get session object by key
>
> set(key, sess, maxAge, { rolling, changed }): set session object for key, with a maxAge (in ms)
>
> destroy(key): destroy session for key

After asking around, I did this:

```js
//  middleware/installSession.js
const session = require('koa-session');
const RedisStore = require('koa-redis');
const ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

module.exports = function installSession(app) {
  app.keys = [process.env.SECRET];

  app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore({
      url: process.env.REDIS_URL,
      key: process.env.REDIS_STORE_KEY,
      async get(key) {
        const res = await redis.get(key);
        if (!res) return null;
        return JSON.parse(res);
      },

      async set(key, value, maxAge) {
        maxAge = typeof maxAge === 'number' ? maxAge : ONE_DAY;
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
        await redis.set(key, value, 'PX', maxAge);
      },

      async destroy(key) {
        await redis.del(key);
      },
    })
  }, app));
};
```

Then in my main `server.js` file:

```js
// server.js
...
const middleware = require('./middleware');

const app = new Koa();
const server = http.createServer(app.callback());

// session middleware
middleware.installSession(app);

// other middleware, which also get app as a parameter
middleware.installFirebaseAuth(app);
...
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
server.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
```

But then how do I access the session and its methods from inside other middlewares? Like in the `installFirebaseAuth` middleware, I want to finally get/set session values:

```js
// installFirebaseAuth.js
...

module.exports = function installFirebaseAuth(app) {
  ...
  const verifyAccessToken = async (ctx, next) => {
      ...

      // trying to access the session, none work
      console.log('ctx.session', ctx.session);
      console.log('ctx.session.get():'
      ctx.session.get(process.env.REDIS_STORE_KEY));
      console.log('ctx.req.session', ctx.req.session);
      const redisValue = await ctx.req.session.get(process.env.REDIS_STORE_KEY);
      ...
   }
}
```

`ctx.session` returns `{}`

`ctx.session.get()` returns `ctx.session.get is not a function`

`ctx.req.session` returns `undefined`

Any clues?
Thanks!!

Comment: I know it's a bit old but have you found the solution?

Comment: not really, I gave up on Koa a while ago....

Comment: Their docs are a disaster compared to express. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

It works in my case, hope it helps you

```js
const Koa = require('koa')
const app = new Koa()

const Router = require('koa-router')
const router = new Router()

const static = require('koa-static')
const session = require('koa-session')
// const ioredis = require('ioredis')
// const redisStore = new ioredis()
const redisStore = require('koa-redis')
const bodyparser = require('koa-bodyparser')

app.use(static('.'))
app.use(bodyparser())
app.keys = ['ohkeydoekey']
app.use(session({
  key: 'yokiijay:sess',
  maxAge: 1000*20,
  store: redisStore()
}, app))

app.use(router.routes(), router.allowedMethods())

router.post('/login', async ctx=>{
  const {username} = ctx.request.body
  if(username == 'yokiijay'){
    ctx.session.user = username
    const count = ctx.session.count || 0
    ctx.session.code = count
    ctx.body = `wellcome ${username} logged in`
  }else {
    ctx.body = `sorry, you can't login`
  }
})

router.get('/iflogin', async ctx=>{
  if(ctx.session.user){
    ctx.body = ctx.session
  }else {
    ctx.body = 'you need login'
  }
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log( 'app running' )
})
```

Comment: That actually doesn't work. If you look at the contents of your redis store, you will notice it is not creating any sessions. As of this day, the packages koa-session and koa-redis are not compatible.

koa-session is simply defaulting to an in-memory store implementation.